# Filtering Outlook conversations started by a particular user

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I setup Outlook 2010 to automatically filter all conversations *started* by a particular user and move them to another folder?

Example: X sends emails to me and other people. Some of us respond to X's emails. I would like to have all emails sent by X and all replies to those emails be automatically moved to another folder.

Thanks.